# Why is possible to call static methods of a non-static class?

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine, static-members, static-classes

Taking into consideration the following class structure:

[PUBLIC NON-STATIC CLASS]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static void Play() //STATIC METHOD
    {
        print("Play some audio!");
    }

}
```

ANOTHER CLASS CALLING:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestClass : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GameManager.Play();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Because it is possible to call this method without instantiating the class GameManager?

Comment: because it is static no need to create object out of it

Comment: right.. but my class is not static.. Therefore, it is not required that the class is to have static methods static right?

Comment: no need static class to have static methods

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

> A static class is basically the same as a non-static class, but there
>   is one difference: a static class cannot be instantiated

The fact that it's not a static class doesn't affect the way static methods can be used.

Comment: Thanks! Its too help me https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms998558.aspx - Singleton

Comment: Sidenote, I think it's kinda funny how the docs say "It's basically the same" then it says it can't be instantiated, which is a HUGE difference and makes it totally not "basically the same". Classic Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods are often used in a non-static class for utility methods.  They can also be used for masking modifiers and constructors on immutable types by returning a new object from the requested manipulation.  See java String.

Comment: Thanks bro! Its nice :)

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty comes from the fact that 'static' has a slightly different meaning for methods and for classes.

1. Static classes cannot be instantiated
2. Static methods are associated with the class rather than objects, so you don't need to create an object to call a static method. However, it does not matter if the class itself is static or not.

See the relevant documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When a method is declared **static**, it can be accessed before any objects of its class are created, and without reference to any object and a non-static class can contain static methods too.